# Multiple dynamic fields with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm using the following solution that allows me to have multiple dynamic form fields: http://www.trovster.com/lab/plugins/duplicate-remove/

However, in one of those fields, i want to create jQuery UI datepicker. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looking @ that plugin it seems to only duplicate given elements. So presumably if you were wanting to duplicate multiple date-picker elements it should work fine. The only problem I can see you running into is if you generate the date-picker dynamically, you may have to re-render the date-picker each time you duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something like the livequery plugin or the built in live() feature of jQuery that listens for DOM changes and applies code to whatever you are listening for.